# What's the function like sum() but for multiplication? product()?

Tags: python, multiplication

Python's [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) function returns the sum of numbers in an iterable.

```
sum([3,4,5]) == 3 + 4 + 5 == 12
```

I'm looking for the function that returns the product instead.

```
somelib.somefunc([3,4,5]) == 3 * 4 * 5 == 60
```

I'm pretty sure such a function exists, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

## **Update:**

In Python 3.8, the *prod* function was added to the *math* module.  See: [math.prod()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod).

### Older info: Python 3.7 and prior

The function you're looking for would be called *prod()* or *product()* but Python doesn't have that function.  So, you need to write your own (which is easy).

### Pronouncement on prod()

Yes, that's right.  Guido [rejected the idea](http://bugs.python.org/issue1093) for a built-in prod() function because he thought it was rarely needed.

### Alternative with reduce()

As you suggested, it is not hard to make your own using [*reduce()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce) and [*operator.mul()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
from functools import reduce  # Required in Python 3
import operator
def prod(iterable):
    return reduce(operator.mul, iterable, 1)

>>> prod(range(1, 5))
24
```

Note, in Python 3, the [*reduce()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function was moved to the [functools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

### Specific case: Factorials

As a side note, the primary motivating use case for *prod()* is to compute factorials.  We already have support for that in the [math module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/math.html#math.factorial):

```
>>> import math

>>> math.factorial(10)
3628800
```

### Alternative with logarithms

If your data consists of floats, you can compute a product using *sum()* with exponents and logarithms:

```
>>> from math import log, exp

>>> data = [1.2, 1.5, 2.5, 0.9, 14.2, 3.8]
>>> exp(sum(map(log, data)))
218.53799999999993

>>> 1.2 * 1.5 * 2.5 * 0.9 * 14.2 * 3.8
218.53799999999998
```

Note, the use of *log()* requires that all the inputs are positive.

Comment: You might want to add that the floats in the last example need to be _positive_. Otherwise, you might have to use cmath, but even then it won't really work in all cases.

Answer (score 239):

Historically, Guido vetoed the idea: http://bugs.python.org/issue1093

As noted in that issue, you can make your own:

```
from functools import reduce # Valid in Python 2.6+, required in Python 3
import operator

reduce(operator.mul, (3, 4, 5), 1)
```

Comment: Here is a great example of where there is a "need for this," to quote Guido: product(filter(None, [1,2,3,None])). Hopefully it will be included someday.

Comment: Isn't Guido also the guy who doesn't like `reduce`?

Comment: Yep -- and reduce is no longer even a builtin in Python 3. IMO, we don't need every possible list operator added to the global builtins when a standard (or 3rd party) library would do. The more builtins you have, the more common words become off-limits as local variable names.

Comment: Just found this nugget in [Guido's blog post about reduce()](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). **"We already have sum(); I'd happily trade reduce() for product()..."**. If anyone wants to petition for including `product()` in the standard library, the number of views on this question may help make the case.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney It sounds like python3 already got rid of the reduce builtin. I think product missed its chance. ;)

Comment: @the911s I don't get it, what's wrong with `import operator; print(reduce(operator.mul,filter(None, [1,2,3,None])))`?

Comment: @user202729 `[0, 1, 2, 3]` now results in `6` instead of `0`

Comment: So how come sum() got a free pass then?

Comment: I wish he would've explained his "dissuasion".

Comment: An obvious case of not foreseeing things like Sagemath and the routine need to compute products (as well as sums) of thousands of elements in various algebras in which this is entirely feasible and does not cause the representation to explode.

Answer (score 49):

There's a [`prod()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) in numpy that does what you're asking for.

Comment: note: doesn't support Python longs (arbitrary precision integers) so `np.prod(range(1,13))` gives the correct answer equal to 12! but `np.prod(range(1,14))` does not.

Comment: @JasonS `np.prod(arange(1,14, dtype='object'))`?

Comment: The [`math.prod()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod) function will make this answer obsolete.

Comment: Still tedious to have to import math when you want to do this in a simple one-liner.  I miss reduce() and the Guido-rejected product().

Answer (score 43):

There isn't one built in, but it's simple to roll your own, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493853/which-python-module-is-suitable-for-data-manipulation-in-a-list/494034#494034):

```
import operator
def prod(factors):
    return reduce(operator.mul, factors, 1)
```

See answers to this question:

[Which Python module is suitable for data manipulation in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493853/which-python-module-is-suitable-for-data-manipulation-in-a-list)

Comment: If using Python 3 use `functools.reduce` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: For even more functools fun: `prod = functools.partial(functools.reduce, operator.mul)`

Comment: So in Python 3 I need *two* imports to do something so basic?!

Comment: @A.Donda You need to use imports in Python to do far more basic things: the square root function is in Math, Threads are in threading, etc etc. Python doesn't eschew namespaces, it's actually an explicit part of the Zen of Python that it embraces them.

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze, yes, I agree that namespaces are one honking great idea. But imho in a language that has native lists, multiplying a bunch of numbers should be a builtin. And I consider it to be more basic than square roots and threading. In particular the latter is complex enough to warrant a module.

Comment: @A.Donda Python's "list" is a dynamic array, not a list. But given that python lists and iterators are so important, I would expect 'product' to do a cartesian product of iterables, if anything. Other languages where it's easy to do this usually just have variadic "add" and "times" functions that take any number of arguments, rather than actually operating on lists.

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze, yes, just like 'sum' does a cartesian sum of iterables.

Comment: @A.Donda I'm not aware of that. `sum` calls +, and there is no + defined for general iterators. If there were, it should be chaining (itertools.chain), just like if * were defined on iterators it should do product (itertools.product).

Answer (score 29):

```
Numeric.product
```

( or

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,[3,4,5])
```

)

Comment: He wants a function he can load from a module or library, not writing the function himself.

Comment: But if there isn't one, he probably still wants the function.

Comment: Right, but he needs to know one doesn't exist, since that's his main question.

Comment: You also have to give reduce a default value of 1 otherwise it will fail in the null case. The product of an empty sequence is defined as 1.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen Numeric is (one of) the predecessors of numpy.

Comment: An example of how to use Numeric.product, and how to import it, would make this answer even better!

Answer (score 24):

Use this

```
def prod(iterable):
    p = 1
    for n in iterable:
        p *= n
    return p
```

Since there's no built-in `prod` function.

Comment: you must think reduce really is an antipattern :)

Comment: He wanted to know if an existing function exists that he can use.

Comment: And this answer explainss that there isn't one.

Comment: @zweiterlinde: For beginners, reduce leads to problems.  In this case, using `lambda a,b: a*b`, it isn't a problem.  But reduce doesn't generalize well, and gets abused.  I prefer beginners not learn it.

Comment: @S.Lott I've never seen any beginners use reduce, much less any other functional-esque constructs. Heck, even "intermediate" programmers usually don't know much beyond a list comprehension.

Comment: FWIW this is about 25~30% _faster_ than the `reduce`-based solution

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps not a "builtin", but I consider it builtin. anyways just use numpy

```
import numpy 
prod_sum = numpy.prod(some_list)
```

Comment: That's dangerously close to a "works on my machine" statement!  Numpy, lovely though it is, is unequivocaly *not* a builtin.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the answers [a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/595409/778533) and [b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/595396/778533) above using [functools.reduce()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364663/778533) using [numpy.prod()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html), but here is yet another solution using [itertools.accumulate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
import itertools
import operator
prod = list(itertools.accumulate((3, 4, 5), operator.mul))[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also encode your list of numbers as a `pd.Series` and then use [`pd.Series.product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.product.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series([5,3,-1]).product()
-15
```