# Sum of product of elements in every subsets of an array

Tags: arrays, subset

I need to find sum of product of element in every subset of an array in polynomial time complexity.

e.g., for array `{1,2,3}` required sum will be equal to `null+1+2+3+(1*2)+(1*3)+(2*3)+(1*2*3)`.

All I know is brute-force approach to this problem. Can someone explain how to solve this problem using dynamic programming in `O(n^2)` or `O(n^3)` time complexity?

Comment: Here's a similar question where they specify subset size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106193/sum-of-product-of-subsets

Comment: I want dynamic approach to this problem...can this problem be solved using dynamic programming ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to solve this in O(n) from: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-products-possible-subsets/

The closed form for this for a set {a,b,c,...,z} is:

```
(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)...(z+1) - 1
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16111995)

Comment: This was my first time answering, thank you for your review!