# Multiplying a subset of a list of integers together in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of 10 integers and I want the result of multiplying the first 5 together.  Is there a pythonic way of doing this?  Python seems to be great with lists :)

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-python-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import operator
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print reduce(operator.mul, [v for (k, v,) in enumerate(l) if k < 5])
>> 120
```

Edit: Better way to do it

```
print reduce(operator.mul, l[:5])
>> 120
```

Comment: Why not `reduce(operator.mul, l[:5])` ??  People sure love `enumerate()`.

Comment: Yeah. I edited it for that as you were posting the comment. Still getting used to the "everything is sliceable" thing. Stupid PHP.

Comment: `reduce(operator.mul, itertools.islice(l,5))` avoids making a copy of the list which may matter for large enough slices

Answer (score 4):

Lot's of ways. Here's one:

```
>>> a = range(1,10)
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, a[:5])
120
```

Answer (score 2):

When there are many ways to do something, I turn to criteria such as readability or speed to decide which code to use. Here is some code which suggests that `use_loop` and `use_reduce` are roughly tied in terms of speed (at least for the values tested!)

```
import operator
import itertools

a=range(1,1000)
def use_loop(a,n):
    result=1
    for num in a[:n]:
        result*=num
    return result

def use_reduce(a,n):
    return reduce(operator.mul, a[:n])

def use_reduce_lambda(a,n):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, a[:n])

def use_islice_loop(a,n):
    result=1
    for num in itertools.islice(a,n):
        result*=num
    return result

def use_islice_reduce(a,n):
    return reduce(operator.mul, itertools.islice(a,n))

if __name__=='__main__':
    n=50
    print(use_loop(a,n))
    print(use_reduce(a,n))
    print(use_reduce_lambda(a,n))    
    print(use_islice_loop(a,n))
    print(use_islice_reduce(a,n))
```

Here are the timing results:

```
% python -mtimeit -s"import test" "test.use_loop(test.a,50)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 16.1 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s"import test" "test.use_reduce(test.a,50)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.3 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s"import test" "test.use_islice_loop(test.a,50)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.6 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s"import test" "test.use_islice_reduce(test.a,50)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.2 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s"import test" "test.use_reduce_lambda(test.a,50)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.1 usec per loop
```

At least for the value of `a` (1000) and `n` (50) tested, `itertools.islice` did not seem to help performance. `use_reduce_lambda` was significantly slower than it's cousin `use_reduce`, which used `operator.mul`. The time required to import `operator` was not included in the test, however.

Since `use_loop` and `use_reduce` seem equally fast, I'd suggest using `reduce` since its short, idiomatic code should be quite readable to most python programmers. However, in matters of taste I don't think it pays to be too opinionated. Choose what you like best, just be consistent.

PS. As of Python 3+, `reduce` is no longer a built-in function, but can be accessed through `functools.reduce`.

Comment: can you also try one using `itertools.islice(a,n)` instead of `a[:n]`? Seems to take about the same time for n=50, but when n is much larger it would help

Answer (score 0):

#### Using reduce:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, mylist[:5])
```

e.g.,

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, range(1,5))
24
```

the `reduce()` function applies the given function (here, multiplication) over the first two items of the list, hereby reducing them to one item. This is done until there is only one item in the list. This item is returned as the result. This notation is derived from functional languages.

#### Iterating through the list:

```
result=1
for i in mylist[:5]:
    result*=i
```

e.g,

```
>>> result=1
>>> for i in range(1,5):
    result*=i
>>> result
24
```

This is the most general way of aggregating some function over all items of a list; It is similar to the way this would have been done Java or C.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple function that will do what you want.

```
def multiply(args):
    x= 1
    for arg in args:
       x*= arg
    return x

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

multiply(l)
>>>362880
multiply(l[:5])
>>>120
```