# Python: understanding lambda expressions with two variables

Tags: python, lambda

While looking up concise ways to calculate the product of a list, I was a little confused by this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-python-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication). Here's the code in question:

`reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,[3,4,5])`

Can someone explain why this works? I'm familiar with using `lambda` expressions involving one variable (e.g. when using a custom compare function for [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)) but am confused why and how this works.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  There's nothing magical about lambda: this is the same as `def f(x,y): return x*y` and then `reduce(f, [3,4,5])`.  So is it really the behaviour of `reduce` which is confusing you?

Comment: @DSM: I was confused about `f(x,y)` works to compute the product (why we need `y`). I think @unutbu has explained this well with an example from the documentation.

Comment: You should replace lambdas with simple for-loop in most cases, they are much friendlier to read and there's no performance disadvantage. You don't need `reduce()` either - http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the Python function like sum() but for multiplication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-python-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`lambda x,y: x*y` is an [anonymous function](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) otherwise equivalent to

```
def foo(x, y):
    return x*y
```

---

To understand its use in `reduce(lambda ...)`, consider the example from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

> reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
>   ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).

Similarly, `reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,[3,4,5])` calculates `((3*4)*5)`.

---