# Multiply elements of inner lists as a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, collections, list-comprehension

Could this be done in single line using list comprehension?

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [9]]
products = ?? (Multiple each list elements)
```

Desired output = `[6, 24, 30, 9]`

I tried something like:

```
products = [l[i] * l[i + 1] for l in lst for i in range(len(l) - 1)]
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Do you also need an answer as to why your method didn't work?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to apply multiplication to a list of integers, together with [`operator.mul()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul) to do the actual multiplication:

```
from functools import reduce

from operator import mul

products = [reduce(mul, l) for l in lst]
```

In Python 3, `reduce()` has been moved to [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), hence the supporting `import` statement. As `functools.reduce` exists since Python 2.6, it is simply easier to import it from there if you need to keep your code compatible with both Python 2 and 3.

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [9]]
>>> [reduce(mul, l) for l in lst]
[6, 24, 30, 9]
```

`operator.mul()` can be replaced with `lambda x, y: x * y` but why have a dog and bark yourself?

Comment: Upvoted for `mul`, I had the same answer in mind but with a `lambda` instead, this is nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using [`numpy`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial)

```
>>> from numpy import prod
>>> [prod(x) for x in lst] 
[6, 24, 30, 9]
```

Ref - [Documentation on `prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
products = [reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, l) for l in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `reduce` and a lambda expression within a list comprehension:

```
>>> [reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, innerlst) for innerlst in lst]
[6, 24, 30, 9]
```

Note, in Python 3, `reduce` was moved to the `functools` module so you must import from it there:

`from functools import reduce`

If you don't want to use the lambda expression, it can be replaced entirely by `operator.mul`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-python-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication-prod) solution for making a product operator for lists you can do something like:

```
    lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [9]]
    import operator
    from functools import reduce # Valid in Python 2.6+, required in Python 3
    def prod(numeric_list):
        return reduce(operator.mul, numeric_list, 1)

    [prod(l) for l in lst]
```

Ouput:

```
    Out[1]: [6, 24, 30, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the addition of the [`prod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod) function to the [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html) module:

```
import math

# lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [9], []]
[math.prod(l) for l in lst]
# [6, 24, 30, 9, 1]
```

Note that empty sub-lists will get a product value of `1`, which is defined by the value of `start`:

> math.prod(iterable, *, start=1)