# python - Is there a way to multiple list element together using list comprehension only?

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to learn list comprehension in python but can not find a way to multiply list elements together.
Is it possible using list comprehension?

For example:

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
```

output should be an integer of the multiplication as in:

```
answer= 1*2*3*4
```

Comment: Please explain **multiply list elements together**  with sample input and output.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-python-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication-prod

Comment: List comprehensions are for building lists. You're not trying to build a list, so list comprehensions aren't a good tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `reduce` function:

```
from functools import reduce
r = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [1,2,3,4,5])
# r = 120
```

Comment: you can replace `lambda` by python's inbuilt `mul` ... `from operator import mul` and then pass `mul` to `reduce` func instead of `lambda`...

Answer (score -2):

To itterate through a list you can use:

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
for x in list:
    print(x)
```

Example with your output:

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
stringY=''
for x in list:
    print(x)
    if stringY is not '':
        stringY = stringY + '*' + str(x)
    else:
        stringY = stringY + str(x)

print(stringY)
```

Also have a look here: [Link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) 
This might also show what you are looking for.

Comment: **Is it possible using list comprehension?**

Comment: I know how to iterate through a list with loops, I want to use list comprehension only.

Comment: As somebody above also mentioned, list comprehensions is for building lists. In the question from the Topic Starter, he/she is trying to extract a formula from it. Not building a new list.