# Python: multiply all elements of a list but subtract 1 first

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic and elegant way to multiply the values of all elements of a list minus 1 together in Python?

I.e., calculate (p[0]-1) * (p[1]-1) * ... * (p[n-1]-1) where n is the size of the list p.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) package

```
import numpy as np
np.prod(np.array(p)-1)
```

Or using a python built-in one, e.g. [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)

```
reduce(operator.mul,\ 
       map(lambda el:el-1,\
           p),\
       1)
```

Comment: I am curious of this -1. I would be glad to know why since **this works and adresses the question**.

Answer (score 3):

Use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in python3 along with A.J.'s example:

```
>>> l = [5, 8, 7, 2, 3]
>>> l = [item-1 for item in l] #subtract 1
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, l) #multiply each item
336
>>>
```

Comment: answers with code are enhanced by explanation of what the code does.  Explaining your code will help future users understand what's going on, and adapt your answer to their own needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [5, 8, 7, 2, 3]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*(y-1), l, 1) #multiply each item by its subtracted value
336
>>>
```

Thanks to @AChampion for another improvement

Comment: Note: `reduce` is in `functools` in py3. And you can subtract one in the reduce: `reduce(lambda x, y: x*(y-1), l, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to multiply all the elements of an iterable.

So, given a list `a` you can, for example:

## Use numpy:

```
prod([x-1 for x in a])
```

## Use lambda and functools

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [x-1 for x in a])
```

## Do it manually

```
result=1
for x in [x-1 for x in a]: result*=a
```

---

Note that I used the list comprehension: `[x-1 for x in a]` but it can also be achieved with numpy: `array(a)-1`

---

Related question: [What's the Python function like sum() but for multiplication? product()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-python-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication-product)

Answer (score -1):

```
result = 1
for x in p:
    result *= x - 1
```

Comment: Your answer got flagged as low quality; possibly because you haven't explained how or why this answers the question. I assume the downvote came from the low quality queue.

Comment: @Ben Ok, that might explain it. Morons who can't be bothered to read the question and think that even the most obvious and self-explanatory code needs to be diluted with extra text...

Comment: Or it might be related to python not supporting "*=" and the like operators?