# Python multiply values of list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like this `numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

How can I multiply all the elements of that list between themselves? Like this: `1 * 2 * 3 * 4  * 5`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the function like sum() but for multiplication? product()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication-product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `functools.reduce` (<[python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7)):

```
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
120
>>>
```

Use `math.prod` ([python-3.8](/questions/tagged/python-3.8)+):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.prod([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], start=1)
120
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without importing libraries like this:

```
 def multiplyList(myList): 
    # Multiply elements one by one 
    result = 1
    for x in myList: 
       result = result * x  
    return result  
  
numbers = [1, 2, 3] 
print(multiplyList(numbers))
```

Comment: You could also use this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-multiply-numbers-list-3-different-ways/