# How can I fix "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for this list?

Tags: python, list

Here is a very simple code:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = 1
c = [b*=i for i in a]
print(c)
```

I am trying to multiply all of the numbers in the list a, but I get a syntax error for line 3. How can I fix the code?

Comment: Have you looked at basic python tutorials?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Rfroes87 Multiply all of the numbers in the list a

Comment: You can't use assignment operators inside a list comprehension

Comment: Just remove the =

Comment: What's your expected output? You might be looking for something like `[(b := b*i) for i in a]` in Python 3.8.

Comment: @wjandrea: If they have 3.8, I strongly suspect [they really want `c = math.prod(a)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod). Prior to 3.8, it would be `c = functools.reduce(operator.mul, a, 1)`. Unless they really want a `list` of all the intermediate products *and* the final product (in which case, yes, they want what you suggested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` and the augmented versions like it aren't expressions that evaluate to a value. The issue is, [that's what list comprehensions are expecting](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries): an expression.

> The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least one for clause and zero or more for or if clauses.

To do this, you'd need Python 3.8 and [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
[b := b * i for i in a]
```

There is no augmented version that combines `*` and `:=`.

Consider just using a full loop though.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for this is the following:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

b = reduce(operator.mul, a, 1)

print(b)
```

By the way, this was referenced in this question:

[What's the function like sum() but for multiplication? product()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595374/whats-the-function-like-sum-but-for-multiplication-product)

EDIT: As noted by @ShadowRanger, starting in Python 3.8 you could simplify this to:

```
import math

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

b = math.prod(a)

print(b)
```

Comment: In 3.8+, `math.prod` would do the trick more efficiently/obviously.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't do item assignment inside of a list comprehension.  What you could do is

```
b=1
for x in a:
    b*=x
print(b)
```